# Permission issues with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: permissions

Guys this is my first question here so, sorry if I make any mistake.

I'm having problems with r/w (read/write) since I've installed the recent release of ubuntu 20.04

for example:

- Deleting files - In this gif I select desktop files and press delete , nothing happens

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIfdC.gif

- Generate files from programs are always generated with read-only permissions

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XQFI.png

If someone can help me solving this I would be grateful.

Comment: The second problem is not a "read-only" permission. That's a you-don't-own-it permission. It means that the application is being run by the wrong user (or worst as root), and is usually easy to fix once we know which application and how you are launching it.

Comment: I'm using this aplication with "sudo bash", its an .exe file but with mono

like "mono applicationname argument0 argument1"

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click the file, choose properties and view the Permissions tab; there you can change the read and write permissions (if you own the file) and view ownership status. In second case as you do not own the files in question, you can not delete them or change  the ownership 'as youself'; start a terminal, and run `sudo chown user:user filename`, replacing 'user' with your own username and 'filename' ofc being the file in question. Then you are free to manipulate or remove the file. Or a file owned by someone else can be directly removed with `sudo rm filename`.

It is generally best to avoid running anything with sudo, as it quickly creates all kinds of problems (such as this what you're having).

Comment: The final paragraph is excellent advice!